# You may need me after too many

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> My first, a sight to behold before a drink
>   My second, in the drink
>   My third, a place for a drink
>   My last, what may arise among lads after some drinks

What am I?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think it may be a

> wheelbarrow

My first, a sight to behold before a drink

> WH before a drink (ale) gives a sight to behold.  WHale.  (thanks to @stiv)

My second, in the drink

> you find an EEL in the drink

My third, a place for a drink

> A BAR is a good place for a drink

My last, what may arise among lads after some drinks

> You may witness a ROW among the lads

And the title

> They may have to take you home in a wheelbarrow if you are too drunk to walk

Comment: Almost there! A hint: rot13(Zl svefg vf n fvtug gb orubyq jura orsber n fcrpvsvp qevax. Guvf vf jbeqcynl.)

Comment: Maybe rot13(vs lbh chg JU orsber NYR, n JUNYR zvtug or n terng fvtug gb orubyq?)

Comment: @Stiv Precisely. rot13(junyr-jngpuvat)

Comment: @SteveV Once you have it, please update your answer and I will bestow a green checkmark. :-)